# How to solve error when opening application in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am presenting the following problem and that is when opening my Yii2 application, the charge in my browser as follows  http://localhost/basic/web/ and I get the following error: `Fatal error: Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php on line 77`

[image: Error when opening application]

Comment: THis is related  to the use of PHP 7. You  should update Yii2 to last version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the "**composer update**" command
or **composer.phar update** 
where your composer.json resides