# Unable to open yii2 application using xampp

Tags: php, yii2, xampp, composer-php

I have just installed xampp, placed the project folder in `htdocs`. Install the composer. But when I try to open my web-interface I am getting the error

> Fatal error: Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php on line 77

I searched for the solution and found this [Composer Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49623419/8919244). So I tried to update the composer

`F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)`

After that, I got below error

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - kartik-v/yii2-date-range dev-master requires kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base >=2.0.0 -> satisfiable by kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base[dev-master, 2.0.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - kartik-v/yii2-date-range dev-master requires kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base >=2.0.0 -> satisfiable by kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base[dev-master, 2.0.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for kartik-v/yii2-date-range dev-master -> satisfiable by kartik-v/yii2-date-range[dev-master].
```

**Composer.json**

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
    "luoxiaojun1992/yii2-tinker": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
    "moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel": "*",
    "nirvana-msu/yii2-showloading": "1.0.*@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "~1.7",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-spinner": "@dev",
    "edwinhaq/yii2-simple-loading": "*",
    "c006/yii2-submit-spinner": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "*",
    "fedemotta/yii2-cronjob": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "dev-master",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.2",
    "linslin/yii2-curl": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-dialog": "*",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
    "delight-im/str": "^2.4",
    "mongosoft/yii2-soap-client": "*"


},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": "php init --env=Development --overwrite=n"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "kartik\\spinner\\": "",
        "nirvana\\showloading\\": ""
    }
}
}
```

**Update 1**

In my `composer.json` file I updated `"minimum-stability": "stable"` to ' "minimum-stability": "dev"' and then again tried to update composer. Now I am getting error

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - mongosoft/yii2-soap-client dev-master requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - mongosoft/yii2-soap-client 0.1.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - mongosoft/yii2-soap-client 0.1.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for mongosoft/yii2-soap-client * -> satisfiable by mongosoft/yii2-soap-client[0.1.0, dev-master].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - F:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

**Update 2**

As per suggestion, I have changed `"kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "~1.7"` to `"kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "^2.0"` in my `composer.json` and then I run the command `composer update` via `cmd`, there were no errors and all the updates were successfully done. After that, I tried to run the application but still, it's showing me

> Fatal error: Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php on
>   line 77

How can I get rid of this issue?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Show your composer.json

Comment: @Bizley I have added it

Comment: you need to install stable release of your dependencies only, since your `"minimum-stability"` is `"stable"`, the latest stable for `yii2-date-range` is 1.7.1

Comment: Please read https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14823#issuecomment-394314404 - error stacktrace should point you to the class which uses `Object` instead of `BaseObject`. It could be bug in one of extensions or your app itself.

Comment: remove the vendor directory and change the `"yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",` to `"yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",` and run composer update it should work, also you should replace the fxp-assets with the pakagist `"config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }`

Comment: and remove the `"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
},`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue inside Yii itself. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14823).

There are several option for you:

1. Upgrade yii version to `2.0.13` or higher.
2. Downgrade PHP version to `7.0.23`.
3. Manually replace `Object` with `BaseObject` at the problematic spots.(This is the easiest, yet the worst in terms of quality change).

I recommend doing the first one.

To upgrade the yii version you should run

```
composer self-update
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.4.1" --no-plugins
composer require "yiisoft/yii2:~2.0.13" --update-with-dependencies
```

There might still be this issue, if you are using `Object` class in your own code or you are using an old version of some of the extensions. In that case you should manually replace `Object` with `BaseObject` in your code and either update the extensions or if a new version is not available, manually replace it there too or use another extension.

As @rob006 mentioned below, `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` is no longer needed and you should use packagist instead. You can read more about it in the [article](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md) I gave you in the comments.

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can upgrade it ?

Comment: @Faisal please, try the new changes. Also, you should read up [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md)

Comment: Please do not use `=2.0.13` as a constraint. `composer require "yiisoft/yii2:~2.0.13" --update-with-dependencies` should be enought to upgrade framework to the last version, but this error will still occur if one of extensions uses `Object` class somewhere (this class was not removed from framework for BC reasons, but is is not used by framework itself).

Comment: @rob006 according to the github changelog -> `For compatibiliy with PHP 7.2 which does not allow classes to be named Object anymore, we needed to rename yii\base\Object to yii\base\BaseObject.` There is no BC after 2.0.13 for this.

Comment: @rob006 I agree with the other thing though so I have updated the answer. It is not needed.

Comment: This class is still available in last release of Yii 2: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.24/framework/base/Object.php . But you will not get any error as long you don't try to use it. If you're getting such error it is clearly  application or extension fault, see https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14823#issuecomment-394314404

Comment: Also `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` is nor longer required and it is recommended to use asset packagist instead: https://asset-packagist.org/

Comment: @rob006 Yes, I know, but I gave him the minimum things he needed, He was using the old asset plugin, so I gave him a solution with it. I also gave him an article, where it is explained it is not needed and he should asset packagist instead. He can see there how he can migrate.

Comment: @rob006 I've updated the answer to have all the information from the comments in it.

Comment: @Faisal Please, let me know if this works or further edits are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You've got there `"kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "dev-master"` which means that you ask for latest dev version of the package which is not preferred but you can still get this if you change `"kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "~1.7"` to `"kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "^2.0"` because right now you are blocking it (and this is exactly what the composer information states). [Read more about composer version constraints](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md).

Comment: So I just have to change the version number and that's it ?

Comment: Yes. Something else might happend but you can always play around with versions until you got it right

Comment: You don't have `soap` library installed in your PHP.

Comment: I have enabled the soap extension in `php.ini`

Comment: It must be enabled in PHP CLI as well for composer to detect it.

Comment: After enabling it I again tried to update composer but now again I am facing the previous error

Comment: I have changed `"kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "~1.7"` to `"kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "^2.0"` and then tried to run the application but still it's showing me `Fatal error: Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in F:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php on line 77`